# Access dokku app from same external port without configuring vhost

Tags: dokku

I have a dokku app configuring without a VHOST and the external port number changes upon each new deployment. How can I get access to a consistent external port? I noticed the internal port is consistent so I just need some direction on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I tried using an nginx.conf but since I have no VHOST config, dokku deletes the file on deploy.